# Need to login to Hibernate with Database Username & Password dynamically

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Somewhat like how this link describes :
[Programmatically configure Hibernate with dynamic username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18033288/username-and-password-in-hibernate-configurationfile)

Only,
I need the same implementation, but I am unable to specify `applicationContext.xml` instead of `hibernate.cfg.xml`, since my application specifies hibernate properties in a dataSource inside `applicationContext.xml`
like so

```
<bean id="dataSourceShrms" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.100.155:1546:TSHRMS" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</bean>
```

EDIT :
Use something like JDBC login `conn=DBUtils.getConnection(user, pass, host)` through Java (directly from web app UI), but using **Hibernate**.

Comment: Please elaborate the dynamic part.

Comment: Meaning, after the application has been run and deployed, basically from the web application UI.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
// Get the application context. Alternatively you could implement the ApplicationContextAware interface
@Autowired private ApplicationContext applicationContext;


public void setPassword(String myDynamicallyCalculatedPassword){

   BasicDataSource dataSourceShrms = applicationContext.getBean("dataSourceShrms");
  dataSourceShrms.setPassword(myDynamicallyCalculatedPassword);

}
```

**Note**: According to the [documentation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html#setPassword(java.lang.String)) the set password method:

**This method currently has no effect once the pool has been initialized**. The pool is initialized the first time one of the following methods is invoked: getConnection, setLogwriter, setLoginTimeout, getLoginTimeout, getLogWriter.

So make sure you do not create a connection first. If you cannot do it you could try to create the connection programatically.

Comment: Thanks, but I am stuck here :  
1 ) Reading `applicationcontext.xml` from `/<ProjectName>/WebContent/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml`. As of now I am placing the file in the `.properties` package and reading it like so - `applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/com/org/proj/messages/applicationContext.xml");`
2) After setting dynamic username and password, How do I connect and ensure those values to be used throughout ?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that you have your database *url*, *driverClassname*, *username* and *password* in variables with the same name. On your case those variables would be filled from the input page or wherever the user itroduces that data.

And you have a class *MyClass* class **configured with Hibernate annotations**
on the package *com.myapplication.POJO*

So, you just create Configuration object and query the database:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure()
            .setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle8iDialect")
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", driverClassname)
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", url)
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", username)
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", password)

//In next line you just tell Hibernate which classes are you going to query
configuration = configuration.addPackage("com.myapplication.POJO").
                addAnnotatedClass(MyCustomClass.class);
StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(ssrb.build());

//We open session with database
Session session = factory.openSession();

List<MyCustomClass> result = null;
try {
    //Here we get the list of MyCustomClass objects from database
    result = session.createQuery("FROM MyCustomClass").list();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    session.close();
}
```

**IMPORTANT**: I think **Oracle8iDialect** is the most common for Oracle DB. If you are using *Oracle 10g* or Oracle 9i you should use **org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect** or **org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect**. Complete reference here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html

Comment: Didnt get 'create configuration' part. Will this configure `applicationContext.xml` file ?

Comment: Whit this Configuration object, I just do the following:    `StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb = new    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());    factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(ssrb.build());   Session session = factory.openSession();`  Then you can use the session Object to query the database.

Comment: I am using `applicationContext.xml`. So this will not work. Please suggest a workaround that is pertinent for   `applicationContext.xml`

Comment: I've just changed the solution to fit your specific requiriments. Please check if it works.

Comment: Thank you @JavierFromMadrid, but from what I can understand, this reads url, username, password from `basicDataSource`, like in `basicDataSource.getUsername()` etc. which is from `applicationContext.xml`, which has the values specified. I need to dynamically specify them.
In my existing implementation, I have specified username, password, url,hostname as static values in my dataSource. I need to avoid this and enable the user to enter these values and connect to the database from the application. Like JDBC has in `conn=DBUtils.getConnection(user, pass, host);`, but using Hibernate.

Comment: Updated one more time. Check if it fits.

Comment: Will this work for Hibernate Criteria which I'm already using ?

Answer (score 0):

You can define the Hibernate property as below,

Refer: http://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-hibernate-mysql-example/

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" 
 class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

<property name="dataSource">
  <ref bean="dataSource"/>
</property>

<property name="hibernateProperties">
   <props>
     <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
     <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
   </props>
 </property>    

</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic values in your applicationContext.xml. 
For example you can read values from a external properties file pointed by a Environmental variable that conaints a path to a file:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:${my_environmental_variable_name}/project.properties" />
```

Asuming that your properties file contains:

```
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourapplication
hibernate.connection.username=username
hibernate.connection.password=yourpassword
```

You can use them in yout applicationcontext.xml this way:

```
<bean id="dataSourceShrms" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="${hibernate.connection.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${hibernate.connection.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${hibernate.connection.password}" />
</bean>
```

So you can run your application defining each time a different value for your 'my_environmental_variable_name' environmental variable pointing to different properties configuration file.

Comment: This is the direction is was trying in, but for this i'd have to modify the (for eg.) database.properties file located in a package. I was doubtful of whether this was a correct approach or not. Anyway ran into certain issues when updating that file.

Comment: Maybe the environmental property can contain the configuration properties filename inside your package. Try changing to this <context:property-placeholder location="file:${my_environmental_variable_properties_filename}" /> Feel free to upvote if you consider this answer good enough.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I am aware of this and I have already done so, but I faced issues while modifying the properties file, which I feel is not the right practice. Please refer to my comment above. If you are suggesting modifying the properties file at runtime then pls suggest something in that direction.

Comment: No, i was not talking about modifying the properties file. I was suggesting to use various properties files. i.e.: config1.properties, config2.properties, etc. So when you run your program you can specify wich file to use with the environment variable. i.e.: 'java myClass.class -Dmy_environmental_variable_name=config2.properties'